# How to find_package of a external ros-wrapped library (g2o)

Tags: ros, rosmake, g2o, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have written a ros-wrapper for g2o [0] and wish to do a `find_package(G2O  REQUIRED)` and `include_directories(${G2O_INCLUDE_DIRS})` in my packages CMakeLists.txt

The library includes a FindG2O.cmake file which I also copied to my projects CMakeModules folder(not sure where the file should be), but still the find_package does't work. So, how are you supposed to find_package of external libraries you have written a ros-wrapper for? I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Fuerte.

Another question would be, if the external library you wrapped in ROS, doesn't have a Find.cmake file, do you have to write one yourself in order to use find_package?

Cheers,

Oier

[0] https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56291/how-to-find_package-of-a-external-ros-wrapped-library-(g2o)/) by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 145 on 2013-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'll answer myself. You don't to write a FindFoo.cmake file nor use a find_package in you CMakeLists. The bug was, that my g2o wrapper didn't export the lflags correctly in it Manifest file. For my needs, it had to look like this:

`<cpp cflags="-I${prefix}/include" lflags="-L${prefix}/lib -lg2o_stuff -lg2o_core -lg2o_solver_csparse -lg2o_csparse_extension"/>`

---

Originally posted by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) with karma: 145 on 2013-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0